# Drag drop Image with GWT

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I know this question is all over the internet however I got specific needs. My Images are some objects at least in JAVA code. I need the dragged image to inform another image (the one I drop the first one on) that there was such action executed.

Basically I need to work on instances of dragged Image and Image dropped on on the drag'n'drop action execution

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't tried your specific need, we have been doing drag/drop in GWT with other widget types, using the `gwt-dnd` [library](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/). I would expect it to be of use for you as well.

Cheers,